# mozilla firefox addon settings

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I think there's a file where settings of every addon installed are stored. Where can I find it?
I need the name of the extensions, the version, the state(enabled,disabled,uninstalled) and the extensions ID.

Comment: I think you should reformulate the title of your question to something like "How to get addon details (name, id, version, status) for all installed addons in Firefox?" After all that's what you are looking for, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information you seek is in [$profD](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles)/extensions.json

E. g.

```
{
    "schemaVersion": 17,
    "addons": [
        {
            "id": "addon@example.org",
            "syncGUID": "-3yoR7F-ml47",
            "location": "app-profile",
            "version": "0.0.1.34",
            "type": "extension",
            "internalName": null,
            "updateURL": null,
            "updateKey": null,
            "optionsURL": null,
            "optionsType": null,
            "aboutURL": null,
            "icons": {

            },
            "iconURL": null,
            "icon64URL": null,
            "defaultLocale": {
                "name": "My addon",
                "description": "Addon description",
                "creator": "me",
                "homepageURL": null,
                "developers": [
                    "me"
                ]
            },
            "visible": true,
            "active": false,
            "userDisabled": true,
            "appDisabled": false,
            "descriptor": "/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/w7svh0gr.ffnightly/extensions/addon@example.org",
            "installDate": 1452014720000,
            "updateDate": 1452015546000,
            "applyBackgroundUpdates": 1,
            "bootstrap": true,
            "skinnable": false,
            "size": 147533,
            "sourceURI": "file:///home/user/addon.xpi",
            "releaseNotesURI": null,
            "softDisabled": false,
            "foreignInstall": false,
            "hasBinaryComponents": false,
            "strictCompatibility": false,
            "locales": [

            ],
            "targetApplications": [
                {
                    "id": "{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}",
                    "minVersion": "24.0a1",
                    "maxVersion": "37.0a1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "{aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110}",
                    "minVersion": "25.0a1",
                    "maxVersion": "37.0a1"
                }
            ],
            "targetPlatforms": [

            ],
            "multiprocessCompatible": false,
            "signedState": 0
        },
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to find out the add-on files. Just use the AddonManager.jsm service:

```
const { Cu } = require("chrome");

let AddonManager = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm").AddonManager;

AddonManager.getAddonsByTypes(["extension"], function(addons) {
    var addonData = [];

    for (let i in addons) {
        let cur = addons[i];
        addonData.push({
            id: cur.id.toString(),
            name: cur.name,
            version: cur.version,
            active: cur.isActive
        });
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(addonData, null, '   '));
});
```

For more detail on this just read these [two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager) [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager).